# Las barras no inician en el valor de x deseado

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hola perdon soy nuevo en Matplotlib y tengo un problema tengo 2 consultas a Mysql y obtengo 2 listas de datos para graficar con barras el problema es que la segunda barra  (rojo) deberia comenzar en el punto 06 del eje x y empieza en 01 con la otra barra (verde) Agrego el codigo de las consultas en la segunda el resultado empieza en 06 porque es 0 el valor de los otros periodos ..Muchas gracias

la grafica posee 2 barras de dos consultas pero la barra roja deberia empezar en el punto 06 de x no en el 01

[image]

```
cursor2.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Carga,'%m') as Fechas, ROUND(SUM(Cantidad_Litros),2) as Litros  FROM tablaunion1 where YEAR(Fecha_Carga) = '2017'   and Patente like '"+self.ui.PatenteText.text()+"%' Group by MONTH(Fecha_Carga)")

resultado2 = cursor2.fetchall() 
i = 0

while i < len(resultado2):
    #print(resultado3[i][0])
    #print(resultado3[i][1])
    dates2.append(resultado2[i][0])
    values2.append(resultado2[i][1])
    i= i+1 
cursor2.close()


cursor3.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Fecha,'%m') as Fechas, ROUND(SUM(Kmrecorridos),2) as Km  FROM usitrack where YEAR(Fecha) = '2017'   and  Patente like '"+self.ui.PatenteText.text()+"%' Group by MONTH(Fecha)")
resultado3 = cursor3.fetchall() 
i = 0

while i < len(resultado3):
    #print(resultado3[i][0])
    #print(resultado3[i][1])
    dates3.append(resultado3[i][0])
    values3.append(resultado3[i][1])
    i= i+1 

#print(values3)

cursor3.close()

index3 = np.arange(len(dates3))
    #dates3.append(row[0])
    #values3.append(row[1])



bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.4

ngroups = 12
index = np.arange(ngroups)




#bar1 = plt.bar(index, values, bar_width, alpha=opacity, color='b',label = '2016')
bar2 = plt.bar(index,values2,  bar_width, alpha=opacity, color='g',label = 'Litros')
bar3 = plt.bar(index3+bar_width, values3, bar_width , alpha=opacity, color='r',label = 'Km')

plt.xticks(index+bar_width, dates2 + dates3 , rotation= 30, size = 'small')


plt.legend(loc = "upper left",bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.05), shadow=True)
```

Comment: Hola Julio, sería bueno que aportaras el contenido de las consultas (`resultado2` y `resultado3`) para poder reproducir el problema más fácilmente. Por cierto, deberías considerar usar un `for` para recorrer el cursor y construir las listas, el `while` además de poco "pythónico" es considerablemente menos eficiente.

Comment: Supongo que se debe a que el índice (`index3`) que usas para crear la segunda serie de datos, comienza en cero, igual que el `index` usado para la primera serie. Si debería comenzar en la sexta posición (índice 5) deberías cambiar su generación a `index3 = np.arange(5, 5+len(date3))`

Comment: Si probe con  np.arange(5, 5+len(dates3)) y funciona, pero de que forma quedaria automatico el np.arange porque el valor de dates3=[06,07,08,09,10,11,12]  puede cambiar dependiendo de los datos que estan almacenados. values3= [3000, 4500,......] como muestra el grafico

Comment: Perdon...  ante todo Muchas  Gracias....bueno agrege el valor entregado por resultado3...son  dates3 y values3.. Como mencione dates3 no comienza en el punto 06 del eje x.."np.arange(5, 5+len(dates3)" es una solucion pero no es automatica...¿Deberia crear otro tipo de lazo?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay dos formas de lograr el gráfico que buscas. La primera es usando sólo `matplotlib`, pero no te servirá si quieres pintar tres columnas por dato en lugar de solo dos como en el ejemplo. La segunda es usando `pandas`, y en este caso puedes pintar tantas columnas como quieras.

### Usando sólo matplotlib

No hay necesidad de generar un índice mediante `arange()` para tus datos. Directamente puedes usar como índice la lista de fechas. El inconveniente es que esas fechas no son datos numéricos, sino que entiendo que son cadenas como `"01"`, `"02"`.. etc.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que estos son los datos (las fechas las pongo yo "a mano", los valores los genero aleatoriamente):

```py
import random

dates2 = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']
values2 = [random.randint(1000, 2500) for date in dates2]
dates3 = ['06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11']
values3 = [random.randint(1500, 4000) for date in dates3]
```

Como digo, no necesitas crear las variables `index2` e `index3`, sino que puedes usar directamente `dates2` y `dates3` en su lugar. El problema es en la segunda serie de columnas, que deben salir desplazadas con respecto a la primera. Tú lo lograbas sumando `bar_width` a `index3` y esta operación era posible por ser `index3` un array numpy que permite operaciones vectoriales, pero no será ya posible con `date3` que es una lista de cadenas.

Por suerte, al haber sólo dos columnas, lo que podemos hacer es decirle a matplotlib que en lugar de pintarlas "centradas" en su marca x (lo que hace por defecto), las alinee a su borde (derecho en una serie, izquierdo en la otra). Eso se logra con el parámetro `align="edge"` y especificando un ancho de columna negativo en un caso y positivo en el otro.

En definitiva:

```py
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.4

bar2 = plt.bar(dates2, values2, -bar_width, alpha=opacity, color='g',label = 'Litros', align='edge')
bar3 = plt.bar(dates3, values3, bar_width , alpha=opacity, color='r',label = 'Km', align='edge')
plt.xticks(index+bar_width, dates2 + dates3 , rotation= 30, size = 'small')
plt.legend(loc = "upper left",bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.05), shadow=True)
```

Lo que resulta en:

[image: Resultado]

### Usando pandas

Pandas es una potente biblioteca (que se integra con numpy) para manejar datos tabulados, computar estadísticas, pintar gráficas, y muchas más cosas que te recomiendo mirar en profundidad.

Su uso para este caso sería sencillo. Primero, convertimos tus datos en dos "dataframes" (que es la estructura de datos de pandas, básicamente una tabla con sus filas y columnas). En este caso cada dataframe tiene una única columna (llamada "Litros" en el primer dataframe y "Km" en el segundo). Las filas serían los datos en cada caso, y el índice la fecha.

```py
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame(values2, index=dates2, columns=["Litros"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(values3, index=dates3, columns=["Km"])
```

Seguidamente combinamos ambos dataframes en uno solo, que tendría ya dos columnas ("Litros" y "Km"). Pandas se asegura de alinear los datos que tengan el mismo índice (fecha), y de poner `NaN` (una especie de "None" para valores numéricos) en las celdas en las que faltan datos. Esta seria la fórmula para agrupar los dataframes en uno:

```py
df = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1)
```

Y este sería el aspecto de la tabla resultante (fíjate que ya tenemos un sólo índice-fecha, común para ambas columnas y mira dónde ha puesto `NaN`):

```py
    Litros      Km
01    1688     NaN
02    1210     NaN
03    2041     NaN
04    1125     NaN
05    1004     NaN
06    2495  1558.0
07    2436  2935.0
08    1821  3438.0
09    1120  3597.0
10    1415  2316.0
11    1808  1793.0
12    2200     NaN
```

Pintar estos datos es tan simple como:

```py
df.plot(kind="bar", colors=["g","r"], width=0.7, alpha=0.4, rot=30)
```

El parámetro `alpha` es la opacidad, `width` es el ancho de *ambas* columnas juntas, `rot` es la rotación de las etiquetas del eje x. El resto de cosas (qué poner en los tiks, la leyenda) las decide automáticamente de la información de la tabla `df`.

Sale esto:

[image: Gráfica con pandas]

Como ves, es prácticamente idéntica (y es que pandas por debajo usa matplotlib)

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad que utilizando pandas es mucho mejor ...

Comment: Muchas gracias "abufalia", tu ayuda me ha servido muchisimo.......

Comment: Perdon como puedo votar la respuesta ...soy nuevo

Comment: Al principio de la misma hay un número con flechas encima y debajo, para votar positiva o negativamente, y debajo la marca "V" para aceptarla. Si eres nuevo, echa un vistazo al [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) son unos segundos.

Comment: Ok..Muchas Gracias